# Delay main thread while another thread is running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to import a CSV file in its own thread. While the file is imported and processed I would like to delay/stop the main thread until the processing have ended. See the code below:

```
// Read from CSV file in a seperate thread
new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

    reader = new CSVReader(myFile);
    reader.DataReader();


    // Get temperature and time data from CSV file
    // and copy the data into each List<String>
    Temperature = new List<string>(reader.GetTemperature());
    Time = new List<string>(reader.GetTime());

}).Start();

// Bind data to GridView
dtgCsvData.ItemsSource = Time.Zip(Temperature, (t, c) => new { Time = t, Temperature = c });
```

When the application is running a error occur, since the two Lists are null.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why bother doing the work in a separate thread?

Comment: you should be using Tasks for this... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was created using linqpad...  You can either use a task or async keyword as follows.

```
void Main()
{   
    Task<TimeAndTemp> timeAndTempTask = GetTimeAndTemp();
    timeAndTempTask.ContinueWith (_ => 
        {
            timeAndTempTask.Result.Time.Dump();
            timeAndTempTask.Result.Temperature.Dump();
        }); 
}

Task<TimeAndTemp> GetTimeAndTemp()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TimeAndTemp>();

    new Timer (_ => tcs.SetResult (new TimeAndTemp())).Change (3000, -1);

    return tcs.Task;
}

public class TimeAndTemp
{
    public DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
    public int Temperature = 32;
}
```

async version using async await keywords.

```
async void Main()
{   
    TimeAndTemp tt = await GetTimeAndTemp();

    tt.Time.Dump();
    tt.Temperature.Dump();
}

async Task<TimeAndTemp> GetTimeAndTemp()
{
    return new TimeAndTemp();
}

public class TimeAndTemp
{
    public DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
    public int Temperature = 32;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't really want to stop the main thread.  If this is a GUI application, you still want the main UI thread to respond to Windows messages and the like.  What you want is to run that piece of code after the data has been read.  Why not have it be called by the worked thread after it reads the data?